# Callback node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function f(cb) {
    console.log("f's activity starts.");
    var t = Math.random() *5000;
    function onActivityDone() {
        console.log("f's activity ends.");
        if (cb) cb();
    }   
    setTimeout(onActivityDone, t);  
}

f();
f();
f();

console.log();
```

I'm using this function to do a callback, the task is to not modify the 'f' function.
The output needs to be like this:

```
f's activity starts.
f's activity starts.
f's activity starts.
f's activity ends.
f's activity ends.
f's activity ends.
Done.
```

But for some reason I keep geting

```
f's activity starts.
f's activity starts.
f's activity starts.
Done.
f's activity ends.
f's activity ends.
f's activity ends.
```

Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: I guess console.log(); means 'Done' ?

Comment: the power of asynchronous functions!

Comment: The power of generators!

Comment: @SilviuBurcea If I remember correctly `Done.` is printed by node.js

Comment: @BeNdErR No, I just ran the code and it doesn't print Done(empty line instead).

Answer (score 1):

It is both asynchronous and non-blocking. What you are expecting is blocking behaviour (f blocks console.log). Both f and console.log are ordinary functions which don't block each other.

Blocking functions are considered to be bad. It makes the executing process/thread wait. And it is upto OS to schedule other threads while this waits.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout()` triggers your callback function asynchronously: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.1/api/timers.html#setTimeout

If you want to run these functions after each other, then you'd have to use callbacks (as you already are expecting in `f()`). Then you could call them like this:

```
f(f.bind(this, f))
```

Or you could use some small flow-control library like [runnel](https://npmjs.org/package/runnel) or [async](https://npmjs.org/package/async) (which is a bit bloated)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Mixu's book [here](http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html). Specifically his notes on a series of tasks in section 7.3 (copied here for easy reference).

```
function series(callbacks, last) {
  var results = [];
  function next() {
    var callback = callbacks.shift();
    if(callback) {
      callback(function() {
        results.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        next();
      });
    } else {
      last(results);
    }
  }
  next();
}
// Example task
function async(arg, callback) {
  var delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1) * 100; // random ms
  console.log('async with \''+arg+'\', return in '+delay+' ms');
  setTimeout(function() { callback(arg * 2); }, delay);
}
function final(results) { console.log('Done', results); }

series([
  function(next) { async(1, next); },
  function(next) { async(2, next); },
  function(next) { async(3, next); },
  function(next) { async(4, next); },
  function(next) { async(5, next); },
  function(next) { async(6, next); }
], final);
```